# Sentinel throttle denied service to multiple devices in same network

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, sentinel, cartalyst-sentinel

When I used my laptop and mobile phone to access login page using same network . Sentinel denied my both devices to access when I try more than 5 time wrong credentials only on my laptop.how to avoid to denied phone to access login page .

Comment: The lock is on a per user basis, so try credentials on a different user.

Comment: http://ec2-54-245-170-226.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/login

http://ec2-54-245-170-226.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/register

http://ec2-54-245-170-226.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/activate/{id}/{code}


Here is my program it always show me ip denied service message